# Connecting Logstash to Kafka in Azure through public IP

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, logstash

I'm having trouble connecting Logstash to my Kafka instance running in Azure. My kafka host has a static public IP address. Everything works fine if I spool up a Logstash machines inside the same subnet and connect the two. But, when I try to send data to the kafka instance via the public IP address, I receive errors. For example, trying to connect my Logstash instance from home to the Azure cloud environment.

Here are the relevant config files and what I have tried:

Logstash output:

```
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "my public ip:9092"
    codec => json
    topic_id => "tagger"
  }
```

Before proceeding, netcat verified that I can indeed reach the port on kafka, there is not a firewall in between blocking the connection.

Here is my kafka **server.properties** file with the settings I have tried based on similar problems in other answers.

```
#--------------------------------------------------------#
#Logstash says: Sending batch to Kafka failed. Will retry after a delay. {:batch_size=>1, :failures=>1, :sleep=>0.01}
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.10.100.4:9092
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.10.100.4:9092
#--------------------------------------------------------#
#Logstash says: Sending batch to Kafka failed. Will retry after a delay. {:batch_size=>1, :failures=>1, :sleep=>0.01}
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.10.100.4:9092
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
#--------------------------------------------------------#
#Logstash says: Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {tagger=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://publicip:9092
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
#--------------------------------------------------------#
#Logstash says: Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {tagger=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://publicip:9092,SEC://10.10.100.4:9093
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,SEC://10.10.100.4:9093
#--------------------------------------------------------#
#Logstash says: Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {tagger=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://publicip:9092
advertised.hostname=dnsname.com
```

Lastly, here is the config that worked for me fine when I was running Logstash and Kafka in the same subnet in the Azure environment:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.10.100.4:9092,SSL://10.10.100.4:9093
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.10.100.4:9092,SSL://10.10.100.4:9093
```

This is driving me crazy, Thank you for any help as I continue looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. If you are experiencing this problem and your errors are similar to mine above on the Logstash End, check the kafka logs directory and there is a file named "controller.log".

Here were the errors I was getting:

```
WARN [Controller-1-to-broker-1-send-thread]: Controller 1's connection to broker MYDOMAINNAME:9092 (id: 1 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSe$
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Failed to connect within 30000 ms
```

I ran `netcat -z -v DOMAINNAME 9092` and there was no response. I added the domain name to `/etc/hosts`. It looks like this with zookeeper running on the localhost(127.0.0.1). I am fairly certain zookeeper could not resolve it and so I mapped it back to my localhost.

> 127.0.0.1 MYDOMAIN.com

I then deleted everything in `/tmp/kafka-logs` (BEWARE, LOSES ALL YOUR DATA) and then restarted the server and zookeeper and it works fine now.
What a pain